# Android Studio "Waiting for debugger" hangs, only on certain project

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-studio-2.3

I have a big project in Android Studio, that recently started doing this problem when I try to debug it. I clean the project, rebuild it, no errors at all, then I debug it, and on the phone in stands forever on

> Waiting for Debugger

This happens only on the project I am working on, if I make a new project and try to debug it, it runs without a problem, but on the previous one, it always hangs there and never finishes.

Also, if I try to run the project normally, it's ok, it runs, and then I open Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor, and from there the option to attach a debugger to the process is grey, I can't click it. Why is that? Could it be related to the main problem I am having?

EDIT: Restarting Studo, PC or device not helping

EDIT 2: Deleting the .gradle and .AndroidStudioXXX folders in user folder in Documents seems to have fixed the issue, but it also completely resetted Android Studio, so this is not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Once Invalidate Caches / restart your project. Keep that app is not available in your device.

Comment: restarting of andrid studio, pc and device not helping

Comment: Am nean not restart your android studio goto file chose Invalidate caches / restart option in your project.

Comment: just did it, same thing. Also deleted manually the .gradle folder before doing the invalidate, same